# Unable to copy files into a docker image on aws codebuild

Tags: dockerfile, aws-codebuild

My source folder in github has the following structure

[image]

docker-compose.yml contents

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  my-project:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./devops/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 80:80
```

Dockerfile contents

```
FROM <AWS Container Registry URI>/myimage:latest

COPY ./custom/customfile.php custom
```

This works as expected when using `docker compose build` locally and I can inspect the container Files and `customfile.php` is present.

When I use AWS Codebuild to build this project, I get the following error

```
#7 ERROR: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3737814451/custom: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3737814451/custom: no such file or directory
```

What is the correct build context to set when running this in AWS codebuild?

I also ran `ls` via a buildspec.yml file and the correct contents are listed.